# iOS 7 - Getting warning message while presenting modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Compiling and running using iOS 7 - I am getting warning message: "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged" while presenting modal view controller. I never had problem with iOS 6 or earlier version. Can anyone show if anything changed while presenting the modal view controller?

```
SearchViewController *controller1;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    controller1 = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController-iPad" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
   controller1 = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];
}
controller1.delegate = self;
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:YES];
```

**EDIT ** Here is the code Can someone point out where it is nested.
Looks like they are nested, Please suggest how to link using child viewcontroller pattern.

```
(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        self.loginRootviewController =   [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController-iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
       self.loginRootviewController =   [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    }

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.loginRootviewController];


    DDMenuController *rootController = [[DDMenuController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];
    _menuController = rootController;



    AppMainMenuViewController *leftController = [[AppMainMenuViewController alloc] init];
    rootController.leftViewController = leftController;
    self.loginRootviewController.delegateLogin = leftController;

    self.window.rootViewController = rootController;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Comment: BTW, presentModalViewController:animated: is depreciated, you should use the new method.

Comment: `presentModalViewController:animated:` is deprecated since iOS 6.0 use [presentViewController:animated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:) instead.

Comment: Do not present from navigation controller, instead present from "self". UIKit handles this and will find who's the best candidate to be presenting VC.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A view controller is detached if the story board is not aware of any segues that connect that view controller in any way back to the root view controller.

It's suggested that you create a segue via Interface Builder and call it in code, even for a modal view, if you are using a storyboard.

Even with XCode 4.6.x and iOS 6.x, you got warnings at build time about unattached view controllers.

If you have two storyboards (one for iPhone and one for iPad), you can name the segue the same for each. Segue identifiers only have to be unique per storyboard. So, performing a segue ([performSegueWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:)) with the same identifier can take you to one place on the iPhone and another on the iPad.

Comment: What if the app is not using Storyboard

Comment: @optme, I don't think you'll get that warning then.

Comment: I am still getting warning in iOS 7 Xcode 5. It works well with all older versions. I can ignore warning for now, the bigger problem, 1. rotation does not work for that view. 2. View goes below status bar. Looks like better the solution is to convert all xibs to storyboard and not support any os earlier than 5.0. That is too much work at this point. Other workaround I am using is pushViewController instead of presentViewcontroller and adding custom animation.

Comment: @optme Are you using IIViewDeckController by any chance?

Comment: @SimonH I am using DDMenuViewContorller. Both has same functionality.

Comment: Having similar issues - appears to not play well with Storyboards - Personally if it's early days I'd remove it. If i t is indeed similar to IIVxx

Comment: @SimonH You mean to say that not to use DDMenuViewContorller or IIVxx?   Is there as way like  "@berbie" is saying we have nested view controllers and shall be linked using the child viewcontroller pattern.

Comment: Well dude just create a sample project without the DDMenuVC and do the same thing see if you get the same results. Easiest way to tell. But IMO if DD or like IIV then I'd ditch it.

Comment: @SimonH I will try to use SWRevealViewController looks ok in demos and they have modified/updated for iOS7.

Comment: Try [self addChildViewController:<the one it's moaning about>] as I don't think the current answer is 100% correct i.e. this should also attach it.

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but you'll probably need to add it as a ChildviewController of one of the viewControllers associated with SWReveal , but just add it to one and it should throw an exemption  indicating what it needs to be a child of (if you get it wrong)

Comment: i am getting same error, i am not using storyboard. or even a nib. my app has navigation controller, i am using presentviewcontroller for some image showing thing

Comment: @SimonH you mentioned IIViewDeckController and I'm working in a Universal App that uses IIViewDeckController for the iPhone version, but I'm having the similar problem as OP in the iPad version. I noticed that "popViewControllerAnimated:" is actually calling IIWrapController, even though I'm not using it at all. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I have this symptom and the app has never been within a mile of a storyboard.  Getting the message presenting the MFMailComposeViewController with either `presentViewController:animated:completion:` or `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

Comment: hello I am facing one issue by using DDMenucontroller when i swipe right side a view a white space is occurring when my finger is on screen drag the view to right i can see the white space and i move out my finger from touch it comes to original . how to stop it.Please give suggestion.Now view is acting as spring action

Comment: try this on iOS 8: [self.view.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLER animated:YES];

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was accepted. Using storyboard with segues does not get rid of this warning.

Comment: I am facing the similar problem of detaching view controller. When i dismiss Mail composer my presenting view controller does not shows. I am also using DDMenuViewContorller.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, and me too I was NOT using storyboard (I am working on a three years old project).

In my case the cause was that I did not assign the rootViewController of my application to the window, like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
{
    ...
    self.window.rootViewController = myRootViewController; // I was missing this
    ...
}
```

No more warnings now.

Comment: Getting the message with my app and the rootViewController is set.

Comment: @HotLicks: maybe you are using some nested viewControllers. If this is the case, any nested viewController should have a parentViewController. This parent-child relationship is automatic if you use standard container view controllers (e.g. UINavigationController), otherwise it should be done in code.

See "Implementing a Container View Controller" in UIViewController documentation for more details.

Comment: There appears to be no practical way to set parentViewController in my situation.

Answer (score 18):

This warning normally comes when we try to present a view controller modally in other view controller which is not part of rootViewController, and we just addSubview the view controller's view.

At this stage we should call presentViewController in that view controller which is part of rootViewController.

So we can directly present any view controller in rootViewController

```
UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
[vc presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: this one solved my issue.. But is there any issue if we present a viewcontroller from rootviewcontroller ?

Comment: Great, I was getting this warning and also had some very strange UI problems with SLComposeViewController when trying to show a splash screen when app was in Background. The above fixed everything.

Answer (score 7):

For those using DDMenuViewController, this is an easy fix. Just add `[self addChildViewController:controller];` to `initWithRootViewController`, and to `setRightViewController` and `setLeftViewController`.

Comment: I agree - as per my comment on the currently marked correct answer

Answer (score 4):

To avoid getting the warning in a push navigation, you can directly use :

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And then in your modal view controller, when everything is finished, you can just call :

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Yes, this *works* on iOS7, just tested here     QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
    previewController.delegate = self;
    previewController.dataSource = self;

    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:previewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: try this on iOS 8: [self.view.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLER animated:YES];

Answer (score 2):

This message still may appear when you have nested viewcontrollers.
If that is the case, make sure they are linked using the child viewcontroller pattern.

Comment: Please see above my code in the main part of the question. Looks like they are nested, Please suggest how to link.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using storyboard and get this error, it can happen when trying to automatically present a view from viewDidLoad too quickly. If you call your modal segue after a small amount of time it works without any further warnings.

Comment: You cannot present anything until viewDidAppear.

Comment: the reason is simply that your VC is in transition when viewWillAppear called and not in view hierarchy yet when viewDidLoad triggered. So presenting anything may lead to warnings from UIKit, crash or inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil]; in viewDidAppear fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But rather than it being how I started the view, it was how the view was configured. I had accidentally set the class on the view to the view controller class instead of on the files owner. The clue was that it displayed the view, but some of the styling was missing. The weird thing is that it was working on older versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, if you are using a storyboard, you will want to put the code that is presenting the new view controller in viewDidAppear. It will also get rid of the "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for..." warning.

Answer (score -5):

Under iOS 7, presentModalViewController is deprecated.

I've replaced it with

[self.navigationController pushViewController: View
                                     animated: YES ];

and it fixed a number of errors I was getting.

Worth a try.

Comment: This does not fix the warning mentioned in the question.